# Fluent NHibernate Map Guid to Oracle Varchar2 column

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

Can anyone help  me how to map c# `system.guid` to oracle `varchar2(100)`. I tried using

```
Id(m=>m.Id).Column("xxx").GeneratedBy.Guid();
```

The query generated is without quotes and so failing insert in oracle.

Answer (score 0):

An educated guess.

Id(m=>m.Id).Column("xxx").Not.Nullable()
                .CustomSqlType("varchar2(100)").GeneratedBy.Guid();

CustomSqlType being the new thing to consider.